# how to find ffmpeg-php dll for xampp 1.7.7 and php 5.3.8

Tags: php, xampp, ffmpeg-php

I have problems with installation of ffmpeg-php extension on xampp 1.7.7 and php 5.3.8 on windows. 
Does anyone have the compiled dll of ffmpeg-php for this versions, i know how to install the
extension but i can't find the correct dlls for my php version.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe this thread can be of help: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/732941-how-install-ffmpeg-php-extension-windows

Comment: I already tried this link [http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/732941-how-install-ffmpeg-php-extension-windows), this is for older version of php.

Comment: Or anyone knows how to compile dll from the source code??? Please help i really need this extension :(

Answer (score 1):

This is the best tutorial for that
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=gU49GiWGGAI

if you are using xampp version grater than 1.7.4 you need to install ffmpeg compiled with MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008).
This is the link for ffmpeg compiled with MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008).
http://x32.elijst.nl/ffmpeg6-php53-win32-vc9-all.zip